# Racket: read all the available data from interactive subprocess output

Tags: racket

I want to use a `subprocess` to start an external program and monitor its text output. I want to retrieve all the data written at a given time and then process it. Then later, read all the new data and process it. And do this until the program is stopped.

But the `read` operation seems to be `blocking` all the time. The following code is not working:

```
(let ((stream (process-stdout proc)))
  (for/list ( #:when (char-ready? stream)
             (line (in-lines stream)))
    line)))
```

**Is there a way to read all the *new* data written on the stdout of a subprocess?**

EDIT: I add a test code to avoid misunderstandings

```
#lang racket

(struct process
  (stdout
   stdin))

(define (start-program exe)
  (define-values (s stdout stdin stderr) (subprocess #f #f #f exe))
  (thread (lambda () (copy-port stderr (current-error-port))))
  (process stdout stdin))

(define (send-to proc value)
   (write value  (process-stdin proc))
   (flush-output (process-stdin proc)))

(define (receive-from proc)
  (let ((stream (process-stdout proc)))        
    (for/list ((line (in-lines stream)))                        ;; TODO: seems blocking forever
      (printf "RECEIVE[~a] EOF=~a~%" line (eof-object? stream)) ;; EOF is never #f
      line)))

(define cmd-process (start-program "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"))

(let loop ([x (receive-from cmd-process)])
  (for ((line x))
    (printf "RECEIVE:[~A]~%" x))
  (flush-output)
  ;;
  ;; TODO: how to detect that EVERYTHING has been read
  ;; so that I can input a command such as 'dir' or whatever
  ;;
  ;; I want to avoid parsing strings to detect that I cannot read anymore.
  ;;
  (loop (receive-from cmd-process)))

(close-input-port  (process-stdout cmd-process))
(close-output-port (process-stdin  cmd-process))
```

And the result:

```
RECEIVE[Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535]] EOF=#f
RECEIVE[(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.] EOF=#f
RECEIVE[] EOF=#f ;; <=== I want to get a #t here
```

Comment: Your variable `stream` is a port. It will never be `eof-object?`, so that part of code is definitely wrong. Also, `(for/list (#:when (char-ready? stream) ...)` will check `(char-ready? stream)` only once. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Interesting comment. You are correct, the code seems pretty wrong to me now. And I didn't know `(char-ready? stream)` will be evaluated once. Which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found one possible way to solve my problem using `events`.

```
#lang racket

(struct process
  (process
   stdout
   stdin
   read-event)) ;; add a read event

(define (start-program exe)
  (define-values (proc stdout stdin stderr) (subprocess #f #f #f exe))
  (thread (λ () (copy-port stderr (current-error-port))))
  (process proc stdout stdin (read-line-evt stdout 'any))) ;; create the event

(define (send-to proc value)
   (display value (process-stdin proc))
   (flush-output (process-stdin proc)))

(define (read-all)
  (let ((receive-string (sync/timeout 1 (process-read-event cmd-process)))) ;; read non-blocking
    (when (and receive-string (not (eof-object? receive-string)))
      (printf "RECV:[~A]~%" receive-string)
      (read-all))))

;; MAIN

(define cmd-process (start-program "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"))

(read-all)
(printf "SEND:[DIR]~%")
(send-to cmd-process (format "DIR~A" #\newline))
(read-all)

(printf "[WAIT FOR TERMINATE]~%")
(printf "SEND:[exit]~%")
(send-to cmd-process (format "exit~A" #\newline))
(read-all)
(subprocess-wait (process-process cmd-process))
(printf "[WAIT FOR TERMINATE] ProcessStatus=~A~%"
  (subprocess-status (process-process cmd-process)))

(close-input-port  (process-stdout cmd-process))
(close-output-port (process-stdin  cmd-process))
```

This code gives the expected result, without having to parse string to find the prompt:

```
RECV:[Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535]]
RECV:[(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.]
RECV:[]
SEND:[DIR]
RECV:[E:\>DIR]
RECV:[ Volume in drive E has no label.]
RECV:[ Volume Serial Number is BE25-0CEB]
RECV:[]
RECV:[ Directory of E:\]
RECV:[]
RECV:[12/25/2019  01:18 PM    <DIR>          .]
RECV:[12/25/2019  01:18 PM    <DIR>          ..]
RECV:[               0 File(s)              0 bytes]
RECV:[               2 Dir(s)  163,789,271,040 bytes free]
RECV:[]
[WAIT FOR TERMINATE]
SEND:[exit]
RECV:[E:\>exit]
[WAIT FOR TERMINATE] ProcessStatus=0
```

If somebody find a way to achieve this behavior without `event` I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how blocking is the problem in the above code. It looks like you want your program to report something for each iteration of the loop, but your code didn't do that.

Here's an example that I think it doing what you want. `a.rkt` prints 10 lines:

```
()
(0)
(0 1)
...
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

where each printing is delayed by 1 second.

```
#lang racket

(for ([i 10])
  (writeln (build-list i values))
  (flush-output)
  (sleep 1))
```

Now, `b.rkt` will monitor `a.rkt`'s text output, "retrieving all the data written at a given time and then process it. Then later, read all the new data and process it. And do this until the program is stopped."

```
#lang racket

(match-define (list out in _ err _)
  (process* (find-executable-path "racket")
            "a.rkt"))

(close-output-port in)
(close-input-port err)

(for/list ([line (in-lines out)])
  (define len (string-length line))
  (printf "processed ~a chars\n" len)
  len)

(close-input-port out)
```

The above program outputs:

```
processed 2 chars
processed 3 chars
processed 5 chars
processed 7 chars
processed 9 chars
processed 11 chars
processed 13 chars
processed 15 chars
processed 17 chars
processed 19 chars
```

and returns `'(2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19)`, where each line is immediately output as soon as it is available. That is, every one second.

Please note that the external program (`a.rkt` in this case) needs to flush its output. Without flushing, the output could be buffered, and you might not see the "real time" output when the output still fits in the buffer.

Comment: Actually, it's an interactive program. There is some text to read before a prompt. And then you are allowed to enter some commands. And then you have some commands results to read. And so on. I want to know if there is a way to ask the stream if something new has been receive from the program output.

Comment: One of the problems is that a shell command that echo 1, chaining with sleep for 10 seconds, chaining echo 2 is indistinguishable from echo 1, enter, and then echo 2 unless you parse the output and look for a prompt. 

Can you provide more details about what you want to do? The snippet of code you just added doesn't provide much detail. Will `send-to` be called programmatically? How will users interact with the program? Etc.

Comment: > 2 unless you parse the output and look for a prompt

This is exactly what I want to avoid, because the prompt is different between all the programs.